# Is it possible to sum a column in Lucene (specifically Lucene.Net)

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

In SQL it would be

```
SELECT SUM(Value) 
FROM table
WHERE condition
```

Can I do something like this in Lucene?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.

You can store `DocValues` (for example, a numeric value) with each document and write a custom `Collector` to do the addition.